# Alternatives to Chatterous?

Tags: webapp-rec

My team has been using Chatterous for quite some time now and the service has been getting more and more flaky. We have some team members who use the web client, some who prefer to send and receive via instant messaging and some who want to interact through e-mail.

Chatterous allows you to do this. However, recently it has been randomly unresponsive to IM. Chatterous appears to no longer be under active development and the code is not open source (or we would just install our own Chatterous server).

Anyone have any ideas for alternatives?

I need a "chat room" that will:

- Send and receive messages to a registered IM account (`user@gmail.com` for example)
- Send and receive messages to a registered email account (`user@gmail.com` for example)
- Allow messages to be entered into a web client if you don't want to set it up for use through email/IM.

All messages sent by one of the three methods need to be delivered to all three methods. So if I send an IM to the "group"/"room" that IM gets sent to all people who have their IM account registered, AND an email should be generated and sent to those who have chosen the email route, AND the message should be posted to and visible in the web client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried  **[HipChat](https://www.hipchat.com)** ?

Selection from the [features](https://www.hipchat.com/features) page :

> - desktop and web applications
> - free native apps for iPhone, iPad, and Android with push
>     notifications for imporatant messages.
> - send and receive 1-1 chat messages on any phone via SMS.
> - get Bob's attention by using @Bob in a message. Customize mention
>     notifications to be sent in the app, email, or SMS.

Comment: This is probably as good as it gets. It's not free, and doesn't seem to integrate with google chat, but, oh well...

Answer (score 0):

You could try PartyChat, which is working well for me so far.

http://partychapp.appspot.com/

Comment: Why is this helpful? Can you add some context to your answer - what does the tool do well, why does it solve the question?